# Industry for the districts in a Cyberpunk world

Tags: cities

**What industrial sectors might you expect my world to have?**

I am designing a world, set in the 22nd century, in which a country is divided into nine districts (named after the nine planets). Each district has it's own industry.

- Cyberpunk like era where a lot of newer technology and laws have been made.
- Airships and cybernetic artificial bodies have been designed.
- Each district has one leader or matriarch is in charge of the resources and citizens of that district.
- The work that the citizens do is determined by the industry represented by the district.

Comment: Hi, welcome to worldbuilding. At the moment this requires an answer which makes up a lot of the creative side of your world for you. This creative reign gives an awful lot of different possibilities but only a few that will be what you had in mind. Could you add more information about your world, really try to narrow down what your world looks like, technologies that have arisen, how much work is done by people, what is the social structure like? Your question may be put on hold whilst you consider what to put, once you've provided enough information for this to answered it can be reopened :)

Comment: I think this might depend on how large the country actually is. Can you give a size comparison to a real life country?

Comment: It's a parallel universe of Japan so about the size of Japan

Comment: Basically the world I created is set in the near future, cyberpunk like era where a lot of newer technology and laws have been made. Airships and cybernetic artificial bodies have been designed. Each district has one leader or matriarch is in charge of the resources and citizens of that district. The work that the citizens do is determined by the industry represented by the district (which i need help with).

Comment: I still don't think we have enough information. Does your future have robots who do all the work? Is there a budding VR industry or are we looking at a dystopian future with hardly any advances for the everyday person? There are a lot of different ways we can take this. You can edit your question to add this information in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible Districts to consider:

- **Agricultural:** Your people will definitely need food so having a district devoted to it is always a must. You can have this district be rolling plains of farms or you can go the more modern and futuristic route and have vertical farming for your nation. Imagine having skyscrapers in this districts cities but they all have farms inside them.
- **Manufacturing:** In order to compete with other nations, your country will have to have some way to manufacture goods and products to be used for your people and trade. This district could be composed of slums, mines, lumber yards, and factories or you could run cleaner factories if you want everything to look sleek. It would also work in conjunction with many of the other districts and so could be considered the heart of your country.
- **Trade Hub:** In order to stay viable on the world stage, and in order to make sure that the standards of living in your nation continue to rise, you will need to trade and barter goods. Having a district devotes to commercial Interprises and corporations will generate revenue for your people and can serve as an international hub for trade among other nations. This district would have many businesses and corporations devoted to selling toys and clothing. It could also be a tourist destination and as such have a lot of amusement parks, regular parks, beaches, and hotels.

  -**Entertainment:** This district would behave similar to Hollywood or Las Vegas for the United States. This districts purpose would be to create entertainment for your people and for trade. From video games to movies or even to prostitution, porn, and gambling, anything entertaining that can be distributed to other districts could be made here.
- **Political:** Every country has a seat of power and your country likely isn't that different. Having a district where all the laws are made and leaders meet could prove to be an interesting landscape for your story. The architecture would likely be more refined and organized than the other districts with everything in the district being carefully planed out.
- **Military:** If this version of Japan has a military still, then you could have a military district for your nation. This district would have the largest number of military bases and airfields in the country and would hold considerable power on the national level. It would be an ordered and disciplined district with military personnel on nearly every street and building. You could even divide this district into more such as Covert Intelligence, Airforce, Army, and Naval districts.
- **Science:** In order to advance technologically your nation will need scientists. This district would be the most high tech in the nation where the brightest minds are sent to work on new technologies. You could also divide this into different areas of study such as genetics, robotics, physics, or other engineering and biology research.
- **Religion/Metaphysical:** If your people are religous or if there is magic in your world, then this district could serve as the holy ground or magical schooling for your country. It could work in tandem with the political district, offering advice and counsel to the rulers and also swaying political opinions of the populace into the government's favor. You could also have this sector at odds with the technology one if you wanted.
- **Undesirables/Residential/Hunger Games Area:** Depending on how dystopian you want the country to be, you could a district devoted to to housing the lower class or undesirables of you nation. If someone doesn't fit in any district for instance, they could get sent to this district where they will essentially become slaves and work menial tasks until they die. Alternatively, this could be a major residential zone where a majority of your people live before they take a hyper rail to work in the morning. You could also have this district devoted to housing the arenas for the hunger games you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Alchemists used to relate [each planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alchemical_symbol#Seven_planetary_metals) to a metal. Of course they don't have the full list of planets, but then there [aren't nine planets any more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluto#IAU_classification).

- Gold becomes finance.
- Copper becomes electrical power (copper wires).
- Tin becomes food ("tin cans").

... and so on.